# Simulating Light Curve with the Timmer & Koenig method in Python

Tags: python, light-curve

How to simulate the light curve using the Timmer & Koenig method in python with error bars in each counts generated by that method. I have used astro ML but I doesn't show the error in the counts. Any help would be highly appreciated. Is there any other library in python which can do so? Thank you in advance.

- Timmer, J. & Koenig, M. 1995. Astronomy and Astrophysics, v.300, p.707 [On generating power law noise.](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1995A%26A...300..707T)
- Ritaban, C, et al. 2008 [Correlated Multi-Wave Band Variability in the Blazar 3C 279 from 1996 to 2007](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008ApJ...689...79C/abstract)